# Can the landlord force viewing of apartment during lockdown? (England)

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property, england-and-wales, tenant

My landlord is considering selling the flat I am currently renting and would like to arrange viewings. However, we are still in a national COVID lockdown, and I do not feel comfortable letting people in and out of the flat (I also work at home).

Can the landlord force the viewings? What are my rights as a tenant?

Comment: The rules may vary so which part of the UK are you in? England, Wales, Scotland or Northern Ireland?

Comment: England, thank you

Comment: Is there anything in your tenancy agreement about viewings? Generally speaking, you're not required to let anyone into the property, unless it's an emergency, or unless your tenancy agreement makes provision for it (and even then, 24 hours' notice is typically required).

Comment: @giac Here's the [Government's non-statutory guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/covid-19-and-renting-guidance-for-landlords-tenants-and-local-authorities/coronavirus-covid-19-guidance-for-landlords-and-tenants) that may assist.

Comment: thank you very much